Passing a new suit at the two level
In first seat partner opens at the one level. Partner's LHO overcalls at the one level. Responder (in third seat) bids a new suit at the two level. E.g. 1H-1S-2C. Can opener pass this 2c bid?

Which bidding agreement are you using?

SAYC Intermediate

Standard bidding in America treats this 2C bid as forcing for one round.

This is a matter of partnership agreement.
Most partnerships in North America (and I believe in other English-speaking countries as well) treat this 2C bid as forcing (and promising around 10+ high card points).
A small minority of partnerships in North America treat this as nonforcing, showing about 7-12 high card points.  In those partnerships, one needs to start with double to force to game (and then the double doesn't necessarily promise 4 of the unbid major).
I believe in continental Europe, the nonforcing treatment is more common, though this also varies by country.

Responder’s new suits are ALWAYS forcing, except for cases you have specifically agreed need not be. That’s how responder captains the bidding.
